# How do I tell lucene to search a complete document?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, morelikethis

I have lucene running and I query it via Solr. The indexes are built, I have a document that contains lots of words, now how to I tell lucene that it has to search the index for the document i provide, what would be the query syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis)? Document ids are quite volatile.